# Processing SASS, JS and HTML + Browser Sync / Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm, rollout

I've been searching for a way that would include following things:

- Process SASS to CSS

  - PostProcess CSS
  - Minify CSS
  - Copy it to a different folder
- Package all Javascript to one file

  - Create backward compatible for older browsers
  - Treeshake
  - Minify JS
  - Copy it to a different folder
- HTML

  - Minify it and copy it to a different folder
- Every time a SASS, JS, HTML file changes process would happen
- Browser would be refreshed

So far I have got to make a single package using RolloutJS but the problem is that I would like to include CSS as an external file linked from HTML file.

Any tips or tricks? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use grunt js have a look on this 
video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMKj0BxzVgw

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using nodejs based tools like gulpjs, gruntjs. This way requires some learning. Otherwise you could opt for a gui application like prepros that is not a freeware (license is quite cheap). The advantage of the latter one is that it can be easily used by colleagues without JS knowledge.